# Is it possible to set cmake variables with add_subdirectory?

Tags: cmake

I am currently using `add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glfw)` to add glfw to my project.

The problem is that once I do cmake .. && make it always builds all the examples and I don't want that to happen.

In the cmake file from glfw there is

```
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build the GLFW example programs" ON)
```

Is it possible to set this variable to `OFF` from my CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply do either

```
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build the GLFW example programs")
```

before the `add_subdirectory` command or

```
cmake -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF ..
```

on the command line

For example given the following two CMake scripts

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

set(OVERRIDE FALSE CACHE BOOL "")

if(OVERRIDE)
    message(STATUS "Overriding option")
    set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build the GLFW example programs")
endif()

message(STATUS "OPT BEFORE =${GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES}")
add_subdirectory(subdir)
message(STATUS "OPT AFTER=${GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES}")
```

and subdir/CMakeLists.txt

```
option(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES "Build the GLFW example programs" ON)
```

you see the following (when run in the build directory

With no command line options, the `option()` command sets the variable

```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake ..
...
-- OPT BEFORE =
-- OPT AFTER=ON
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Turning on the over-ride, the `set()` command overrides the `option()` command

```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake .. -DOVERRIDE=ON
...
-- Overriding option
-- OPT BEFORE =OFF
-- OPT AFTER=OFF
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

You can also over-ride the `option()` directly on the command line.

```
$ rm -rf *
$ cmake .. -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
...
-- OPT BEFORE =OFF
-- OPT AFTER=OFF
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Note that I do an `rm -rf *` in the build directory each time. The value of `GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES` is cached in a file called `CMakeCache.txt`. CMake will always use the values it finds there before anything set in a `set` or `option` command.

Comment: I already tried `set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build the GLFW example programs")` and it had no effect. I added it before and after add_subdirectory.

Comment: Delete your cached variables in CMakeCache.txt in the build directory